# Loop with grepl in R

Tags: r, loops, grepl

I have a text file that I am trying to extract variable information from. The issue is that the variable information is across multiple vector elements within a messy text file and I want to concatenate the variable information together:

My text file is called a character vector called "raw"

For example in the data - elements 34:37(34 = variable name, 35 = variable length, 36 = variable desc, 37 = variable position) are:

```
"HUFINAL\t"            "3\t"                  "FINAL OUTCOME CODE\t" "24 - 26"
```

The concatenated result I would like is:

```
"HUFINAL\t3\tFINAL OUTCOME CODE\t24 - 26"
```

Another example - elements 92:95 in the data are:

```
[1] "HETENURE\t"                                            
[2] "2\t"                                                   
[3] "ARE YOUR LIVING QUARTERS... (READ ANSWER CATEGORIES)\t"
[4] "29 - 30"
```

The concatenated result I would like is:

```
"HETENURE\t2\tARE YOUR LIVING QUARTERS... (READ ANSWER CATEGORIES)\t29 - 30"
```

Since the text document is full of many other lines and I just want to locate and concatenate certain lines that contain variable information, I think I will need to use some type of `grepl` and loop through

This is my crude attempt at something like that:

```
loop<- function(v){
    
    for(i in v) {
        
    if_else(grepl(pattern = "^\\w+\\\t", x = raw[i]) == TRUE,if_else(grepl(pattern = "^\\d+\\\t", 
    x =    raw[i]) == TRUE, print(paste0(raw[i], raw[i], collapse="")), "no match second element"), "something_else")

    }
}
```

So what I tried to do is setting up two `grepl`, one for finding a variable name that ends with a \t using the first regex pattern - e.g. HUFINAL\t OR HETENURE\t and another `grepl` to search in the next element if there is something that resembles a "3\t" or "2\t" (which is the variable length)

If those two `grepls` are TRUE, then I'm pretty sure I've located the 4 sequential lines that have the variable information (var name, var length, var description, and var position) and I should concatenate them together.

Does anyone know how I should approach this? Hopefully it makes sense!

Thank you,
David

Comment: (1) If you are iterating over elements of a vector, `if_else` is wrong, just use `if` and `else` when you are doing a single comparison. (2) `grepl` is vectorized, so don't use a loop, just `grepl("...", raw)` will return a `logical` vector, and now we're back to using `if_else` (yes, it's now appropriate again). (3) `print` inside of `if_else` makes no sense, it should be a value itself.

Comment: (4) Your desired results are perfectly `paste(vec, collapse="")`. I'm going to guess that what you're hoping to do is aggregate a larger vector into fewer concatenated elements, but you haven't given enough information to be able to be able to do that well. Please include more context in your sample data. Thanks!